# problemas com ao tentar pegar o id do pedido

Tags: java, android

bom estou tentando fazer cadastrar um pedido, porem tenho duas tabelas, pedido e pedido_produto, e uma tela onde preencho todas as informações e clico para concluir.

Primeiramente o aplicativo faz um insert na tabela pedido, em seguida faz outro na tabela pedido_produto, mas para fazer o insert na tabela pedido_produto o aplicativo deve pegar o id do pedido, então fiz uma select buscando esse id antes de realizar a inserção, porem não estou conseguindo recuperar este id, vamos aos códigos:

btnConcluir:

```
Button confirma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmar);
    confirma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());

            EditText data = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtData);
            EditText emissao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtEmissao);
            EditText obs = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtObs);

            String dataString = data.getText().toString();
            String emissaoString = emissao.getText().toString();
            String obsString = obs.getText().toString();
            String resultadoPe;
            String resultadoPp;

            Spinner spClientes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spCliente);
            Spinner spCarteira = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spCarteira);
            Spinner spPagamentos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPagamento);

            SQLiteCursor dadosClientes = (SQLiteCursor) spClientes.getAdapter().getItem(
                    spClientes.getSelectedItemPosition());

            SQLiteCursor dadosCarteira = (SQLiteCursor) spCarteira.getAdapter().getItem(
                    spCarteira.getSelectedItemPosition());

            SQLiteCursor dadosPagamentos = (SQLiteCursor) spPagamentos.getAdapter().getItem(
                    spPagamentos.getSelectedItemPosition());

            String idCliente = String.valueOf(dadosClientes.getInt(0));
            String idCarteira = String.valueOf(dadosCarteira.getInt(0));
            String idPagamento = String.valueOf(dadosPagamentos.getInt(0));

            crud.op = 2;

            resultadoPe = crud.insereDados(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                    null, null, null, null, idCliente, idPagamento, idCarteira, dataString,
                    emissaoString, obsString, null, null, null, null, null);

            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), resultadoPe, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            final Cursor cursor = crud.pegarIdPedido();
            pedId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CriaBanco.getPedId()));
            ArrayList<Produtos> produtos = produtosAdapter.getProdutos();
            int linhas = produtos.size();

            for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++ ){

                crud.op = 3;

                Produtos linha = produtos.get(i);
                String id = linha.getId();
                String qtd = linha.getQuantidade();
                String preco = linha.getPreco();

                int ipreco = Integer.parseInt(preco);
                int iqtd = Integer.parseInt(qtd);
                int itotal = ipreco / iqtd;

                String stotal = String.valueOf(itotal);

                resultadoPp = crud.insereDados(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                        null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, pedId,
                        id, qtd, preco, stotal);

                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), resultadoPp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

PegarIdPedido:

```
public  Cursor pegarIdPedido(){
    Cursor cursor;

    db = banco.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(" + banco.getPedId() + ") AS " + banco.getPedTabela() +
            " FROM " + banco.getPedTabela(), null);

    if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();
    return cursor;
}
```

é nesta linha que esta o problema:

```
pedId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CriaBanco.getPedId()));
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Observação: quando executo o aplicativo e chega neste trecho, não ocorre nenhum erro no Android Monitor, mas o aplicativo é forçado a fechar.

obrigado desde já!

---EDIT---

inserirDados:

```
public String insereDados
        (String nome, String apelido, String cpf, String rg, String endereco, String bairro,
         String municipio, String uf, String cep, String email, String fone, String cla,
         String par, String car, String cpag, String data, String emissao, String obs, String ped,
         String pro, String quantidade, String unitario, String item /**String lpPcodigo,
         String lpDescri, String lpQtd, String lpPreco*/){

    long resultadoC = -1;
    long resultadoPe = -1;
    long resultadoPr = -1;
    //long resultadoLp = -1;
    db = banco.getWritableDatabase();


    switch (op){
        case 1://Insere cliente:
            ContentValues cvc;
            cvc = new ContentValues();

            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParNome(), nome);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParApelido(), apelido);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParCpf(), cpf);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParRg(), rg);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParEndereco(), endereco);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParBairro(), bairro);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParMunicipio(), municipio);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParUf(), uf);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParCep(), cep);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParEmail(), email);
            cvc.put(CriaBanco.getParFone(), fone);

            resultadoC = db.insert(CriaBanco.getParTabela(), null, cvc);
            break;

        case 2://Insere Pedido
            ContentValues cvpe;
            cvpe = new ContentValues();

            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getClaId(), cla);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getPparId(), par);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getCarId(), car);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getCpagId(), cpag);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getPedData(), data);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getPedEmissao(), emissao);
            cvpe.put(CriaBanco.getPedObs(), obs);

            resultadoPe = db.insert(CriaBanco.getPedTabela(), null, cvpe);
            break;

        case 3: // Insere Pedido Produto

            ContentValues cvpr;
            cvpr = new ContentValues();

            cvpr.put(CriaBanco.getPppedId(), ped);
            cvpr.put(CriaBanco.getPpproId(), pro);
            cvpr.put(CriaBanco.getPproQnt(), quantidade);
            cvpr.put(CriaBanco.getPproUnit(), unitario);
            cvpr.put(CriaBanco.getPproItem(), item);

            resultadoPr = db.insert(CriaBanco.getPprodTabela(), null, cvpr);
            break;

    }
    db.close();

    if (resultadoC != -1){
        return "Cliente inserido com sucesso!";
    }else if(resultadoPe != -1 || resultadoPr != -1){
        return "Pedido realizado com sucesso!";
    }/**else if(resultadoLp != -1) {
        return "Produto adicionado a lista com sucesso!";
    }*/else{
        return "Erro ao inserir registro (cliente/pedido)!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Poste o método que usa para fazer o *insert* do pedido.

Comment: atualizei o post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

já resolvi este problema

era apenas trocar isto:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(" + banco.getPedId() + ") AS " + banco.getPedTabela() +
        " FROM " + banco.getPedTabela(), null);
```

por isto:

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(_id) AS _id FROM PEDIDO", null);
```

agradeço a atenção.

Comment: A forma habitual de obter o id de um registo na altura em que é inserido é guardar o valor retornado por `db.insert()`.